# calling the (default) hash function for a vector

Tags: c++, hash, syntax

I'm trying to get the hash of different types of objects, like strings and vectors.

The following code is ok...

```
  std::string data = std::string("abc");
  std::cout << std::hash<std::string>()(data) << std::endl;
```

... but not this one although I "just" replaced the *string* type by the *vector* type.

```
  std::vector<int> data( {1,2,3} );
  std::cout << std::hash<std::vector<int> >()(data) << std::endl;
```

*g++ -std=gnu+11* says :

```
  invalid use of incomplete type 'struct std::hash<std::vector<int> >'
```

... why ?

Comment: There is no specialization of `std::hash<>` for type `std::vector<int>`. The error is telling you this. There *is* one for `std::string` (obviously). See [the documentation for **`std::hash<>`**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/hash) for a list of what basic and library types have library-provided specializations.

Comment: Thank you for the explanations about the *meaning* of the error and for the usefull links.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like your compiler doesn't implement `std::hash` for `std::vector`.

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb982987.aspx), Visual Studio only implements this for scalar types and some string types. According to [cpluplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/functional/hash/), compilers are only required to implement this for simple types, not all types.