# hash function for a vector of pair<int, int>

Tags: c++, vector, hash

I'm trying to implement an *unordered_map* for a vector< pair < int,int> >. Since [there's no such default hash function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23836905/calling-the-default-hash-function-for-a-vector), I tried to imagine a function of my own :

```
struct ObjectHasher
{
  std::size_t operator()(const Object& k) const
  {
    std::string h_string("");
    for (auto i = k.vec.begin(); i != k.vec.end(); ++i)
    {
      h_string.push_back(97+i->first);
      h_string.push_back(47); // '-'
      h_string.push_back(97+i->second);
      h_string.push_back(43); // '+'
    }
    return std::hash<std::string>()(h_string);
  }
};
```

The main idea is to change the list of integers, say **( (97, 98), (105, 107) )** into a formatted string like **"a-b+i-k"** and to compute its hash thanks to hash < string >(). I choosed the 97, 48 and 43 numbers only to allow the hash string to be easily displayed in a terminal during my tests.

I know this kind of function might be a very naive idea since a good hash function should be **fast** and **strong against collisions**. Well, if the integers given to push_back() are greater than 255 I don't know what might happen... So, what do you think of the following questions :

- (1) is my function ok for big integers ?
- (2) is my function ok for all environments/platforms ?
- (3) is my function too slow to be a hash function ?
- (4) ... do you have anything better ?

Comment: Writing a good hast function can be very hard. It might be better to use a std::map instead of an unordered_map with a poor hash function.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

All you need is a function to "hash in" an integer. You can steal such a function from boost:

```
template <class T>
inline void hash_combine(std::size_t& seed, const T& v)
{
    std::hash<T> hasher;
    seed ^= std::hash<T>(v) + 0x9e3779b9 + (seed<<6) + (seed>>2);
}
```

Now your function is trivial:

```
struct ObjectHasher
{
  std::size_t operator()(const Object& k) const
  {
    std::size_t hash = 0;
    for (auto i = k.vec.begin(); i != k.vec.end(); ++i)
    {
      hash_combine(hash, i->first);
      hash_combine(hash, i->second);
    }
    return hash;
  }
};
```

Comment: It's just an algorithm known to distribute the hashed values reasonably well (spread single-bit differences over as many output bits as possible). Knuth proved that a prime close to (2^32 / [(sqrt(5)+1)/2]) works best. There are lots of other hashing algorithms you could use.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Wouldn't this produce the same hash for the map containing the list (1, 2) as a map containing the list (2, 1) since xor is associative?

Comment: @mclaassen No, because the seed is also used in ways that are not associative.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Oh ok I see, you are also using the last value to compute the hash that then gets XORed

Comment: Thank you very much : I'm impressed by the quality of your answer.

Comment: `std::hash<T> hasher;` seems to serve no purpose, but presumably you really meant that the following line should invoke `operator()` on it instead of the syntactical error of trying to pass the hashed value to its constructor; it's easy to forget that it's not a function overload, rather a function object.

Answer (score 2):

This function is is probably very slow compared to other hash functions since it uses dynamic memory allocation. Also `std::hash<std::string>` Is not a very good hash function since it is very general. It's probably better to XOR all ints and use `std::hash<int>`.

Comment: I don't think XORing all the numbers together works, there would be a very high rate of collision.

Comment: if `sizeof (int) == sizeof(size_t)` it's nearly the best you can get. It's also very fast.

Comment: @TNA XORing all the numbers would be the same regardless of the order you did it in. So it wouldnt capture the difference between say a number 5 being the 1st or 2nd number in the pair or whether that 5 was paired with a one number vs another

Answer (score 1):

This is a perfectly valid solution. All a hash function needs is a sequence of bytes and by concatenating your elements together as a string you are providing a unique byte representation of the map.

Of course this could become unruly if your map contains a large number of items.